# Is it possible to combine the jackson annotations @JacksonXmlText and @JsonRawValue?

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to ensure that some serialized XML values are HTML escaped. If they are HTML escaped before being serialized by Jackson, Jackson tries to double escape the text resulting in invalid strings. To work around this, I tried adding the `@JsonRawValue` annotation to my field. This seems to work, however now the XML is being surrounded by `<content> </content>` tags because the `@JacksonXmlText` annotation does not seem to work now that the `@JsonRawValue` annotation is also present.

I've tried rearranging the order of the annotations. I also tried to configure the Jackson `XmlMapper` so that I do not need to use raw values, but it seems like the XML entity escaping can not be configured easily.

Here is an abridged example class:

```java
public class Message implements Serializable {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "messageID", isAttribute = true)
    private String messageID;

    @JsonRawValue
    @JacksonXmlText
    private String content;
}
```

I am getting results like this:

```xml
<message messageID="Example Id"><content>Example &quot;Value&quot;</content></message>
```

but I would like to get results with no content tags:

```xml
<message messageID="Example Id">Example &quot;Value&quot;</message>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom `Escaper` to escape the HTML as the XML was being written.

```java
static class Escapers implements EscapingWriterFactory { ... }
XMLOutputFactory outF = xmlMapper.getFactory().getXMLOutputFactory();
outF.setProperty(XMLOutputFactory2.P_TEXT_ESCAPER, new Escapers());
```

As far as I can tell, there is no way to combine `@JacksonXmlText` and `@JsonRawValue` as I wanted.